# Uitableviewcontroller with scrollview and in the scrollview a cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFZxp.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXkF.png)i am trying to make a push to another view controller when i tap a cell that is on a scrollview but when i use the func didSelectrowAtIndexPath and run a tap the cell nothing happens ....

do you guys have some ideas ? 
thnx !

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written? `UITableView` is subclass of the `UIScrollView`, and I'm not exactly sure what is your setup.

Comment: can is send you a picture of the setup ? @SaidSikira

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question about how things are set up. I don't understand the scrollview in a tableview cell part?

Comment: @JoeBenton yes i mean this i have a tablviewcontroller -> scrollview in it -> in the scrollview a cell with a content view

Comment: You mean what? We need more details to answer you question. You shouldn't have a scroll view in a cell as the cell itself is inside a scrollview from the tableview and this can cause problems. If you can explain further how you currently have set things up and what you want it would be great.

Comment: @JoeBenton can i send you a picture of the setup from the tableviewcontroller than it would be easier for you  to understand. ]

Comment: You can add it to your question by clicking edit and then clicking the photo icon in the edit toolbar

Comment: Could you help me in a discussion chat? @JoeBenton

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your screenshot you do not need the scrollview inside the tableview as a tableview itself adds a scrollview for you. Try removing this (and adding the cells straight under the tableview hierarchy) and see if it works.

If not add some code to your question about  how your view controller is set out etc.

Comment: i want the cells to be separate from each other so for example Y 20 than a cel from y 80  and than again y 20 and than another cell is that possible ?

Comment: Maybe do a quick mockup/drawing of what you mean. Either way you don't need that scrollview

Comment: i did look at my post @JoeBenton

Comment: So the "blank" bits in your picture are the gaps. To do this you can divide your table view into sections and use section headers or footers to create a gap between the section. This link will help explain headers/footers: https://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/ios-dev-customize-space-between-sections-in-tableview/